EC.element_to_be_clickable() no encuentra el botón para hacer click
Quiero hacer un proyecto de investigación universitario y para ello necesito recoger data de una página pública de mi país. He intentado automatizar el proceso pero no funciona desde un inicio con la opción de presionar un botón.
Adjunto página y código en jupyter notebook:
Link:
https://apps5.mineco.gob.pe/transparencia/Navegador/Default.aspx
Código:
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://apps5.mineco.gob.pe/transparencia/Navegador/Default.aspx')
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
boton_funcion = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'ctl00_CPH1_BtnFuncion')))
boton_funcion.click()
driver.quit()


El botón (y todo el contenido realmente) está en un frame:
<frame name="frame0" id="frame0" src="Navegar.aspx" scrolling="yes">

Ésto causa que no se pueda localizar el item (NoSuchElementError) contenido dentro del mismo.
Para solucionarlo, simplemente debes esperar a que el frame esté completamente cargado y trasladarte a él antes de buscar el botón:
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://apps5.mineco.gob.pe/transparencia/Navegador/Default.aspx')
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID,'frame0')))
boton_funcion = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "ctl00_CPH1_BtnFuncion")))
boton_funcion.click()
# driver.quit()

